# Accesing individual property from SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, object, simplexml

Before flagging this as duplicate, please note I could not find an answer to my specific case.

I have a SOAP XML response, that I store in an object using:

$resultObj = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml);

if I print_r the object, I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [soap_Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [SubmitNewApplicationShortResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [SubmitNewApplicationShortResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Errors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [IsError] => true
                                        )

                                    [ErrorDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [ErrorDetail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Code] => 209
                                                            [Message] => Client Reference already exists.
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [Token] => 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
                            [ProposalID] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I can access the token using:

```
$token  = (string)$resultObj->soap_Body->SubmitNewApplicationShortResponse->SubmitNewApplicationShortResult->Token
```

However, I don't know how to access the Code and Message properties.
What is that "@attributes" ?

EDIT: seems I had an error in my code and @attributes should be ignored in SimpleXML objects.
This works, as indicated by @mark91:

```
print_r( (string) $resultObj->soap_Body->SubmitNewApplicationShortResponse->SubmitNewApplicationShortResult->Errors->ErrorDetails->ErrorDetail["Code"] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do this?

```
 $resultObj->SubmitNewApplicationResponse->SubmitNewApplicationResult->Errors->ErrorDetails->ErrorDetail["Code"];
```

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I have made a mistake coping and pasting your code: soap_Body is wrong, so I updated my answer properly. Now it should work.

Comment: No, doesn't work, why would it work if you take out soap_Body? I already mentioned that using that part in I do manage to display Token property.

Comment: Well, it seems very strange to me. The way to access attributes is the one I showed you. Can you `print_r($resultObj->SubmitNewApplicationResponse->SubmitNewApplicationResult->Errors->ErrorDetails)` please?

Comment: There is no doubt soap_Body is needed. I appreciate your help, but in this case, you have an error in your code. Look at my question, I clearly specified that I am successfully getting the Token value using $token  = (string)$resultObj->soap_Body->SubmitNewApplicationShortResponse->SubmitNewApplicationShortResult->Token

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot it, I meant: `print_r($resultObj->soap_Body->SubmitNewApplicationResponse->SubmitNewApplicationResult->Errors->ErrorDetails);`

Comment: thank you, your code works, I did however had an error in my question, I used "SubmitNewApplicationResponse" instead of "SubmitNewApplicationShortResponse". I updated the question with the working version and quoted you. I also accepted your answer. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm happy you have solved the problem.